# How to declare this web-service method as global?

Tags: ios, swift, categories, nsmutabledictionary

I am calling one web service and its data I want to use anywhere into project. This is my web service

```
    // MARK: Webservice for Vehicle list
        func CallWebServiceForDISCIPLINELIST() -> Void {

            let successed = {(responseObject: AnyObject) -> Void in
                print(responseObject)
                let code = responseObject["status_code"] as? Int
                if code == 200{
                    self.dict_discipline  = responseObject as! NSMutableDictionary
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.dict_discipline, forKey: "Discipline_list")
                    //HUD.flash(.Success, delay: 2.0)
                }else{
                    UtilityHandler.showAlertWithStatusCode(code!)
                   // HUD.flash(.Error, delay: 2.0)
                }
            }
            let failure = {(error: AnyObject) -> Void in
                print(error)
              //  HUD.flash(.Error, delay: 2.0)
            }
            ServiceHandler.callWebserviceToUploadImageWithParams(nil, imgParams: nil, videoParms: nil, action: DISCIPLINE_LIST, success: successed, failure: failure)

        }
```

And I make one category file of `NSMutableDictionary` for getting it's key and value pair and it is like below. FYI- I put two methods of key and pair, I got 20-30 methods like this

```
import UIKit

class CategoryDiscipline: NSMutableDictionary {

    func getDisciplineList(arr : NSMutableDictionary) -> NSArray {
        let arr : NSArray = arr.valueForKey("discipline_list") as! NSArray
        // print(arr)
        return arr
    }

    func getdiscipline_id(arr : NSMutableDictionary, index : NSInteger) -> NSString {
        let arr : NSArray = self.getDisciplineList(arr).valueForKey("discipline_id") as! NSArray
        let str = arr.objectAtIndex(index)
        //print(str)
        return str as! NSString
    }
    func getdiscipline_name(arr : NSMutableDictionary, index : NSInteger) -> NSString {
        let arr : NSArray = self.getDisciplineList(arr).valueForKey("discipline_name") as! NSArray
        let str = arr.objectAtIndex(index)
        //print(str)
        return str as! NSString
    }
}
```

Till now I try Below cases

1)  I make `extention` of it with return value of `NSMutableDictionary` but it returns before getting response

2) I declare this method into `appdelegate` and call it in `didfinishlaunching` method but when I directed to another view, value is `nil`

3) I store it into `NSUserDefaults` and getting all thing but as an array, But my category file is of `NSMutableDictionary` So its getting fatal error of type casting.

How can I get this web service response in my entire project?

Comment: Are you only handling data or other view animation with this webservice ?

Comment: I use those data to display into actionsheet in different forms into project

Comment: As I mentioned the answer , is not helpful to you ?

Comment: I just getting try of it

Answer (score 1):

I see your cases.... Now I have an approach

First create an global object of AppDelegate:

```
let kAppDelegate = UIApplication .sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

put this line of code in AppDelegate class or create any other class for managing constants. By creating in this way AppDelegate object will persist as long as your app run.

Now call your function anywhere you want, Suppose you want to call in viewWillAppear of all classes then:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        kAppDelegate.CallWebServiceForDISCIPLINELIST()
    }
```

I am sure it will help to you.